# Dynamically update the list based on another cell, Excel

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, dropdown

The master spreadsheet has 700 entries which has categories associated with each of them. The user gets to choose the categories (checkbox) which is of his interest. Based on the selection, the summary sheet should contain the entry details from the master sheet. Each entry has fixed columns. Entire row of each entry is to be copied to summary sheet and not just once cell.

It will be nice to have this dynamically changeable (i.e, user can change his selection and the summary sheet should get automatically updated).

Any help would be appreciated.. With the below code I am not able to append to the existing data. Below statement does not accept lastRow as parameter.

```
Sheets("Sheet4").Cells.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Dest").Cells(lastRow, 1)
```

Code: This needs a lot of cleaning. I am yet to get this working

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Src As Worksheet, Dest As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, j As Long
Dim CellValue As String
Dim SrcSheets As String
Set Src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3") ' Needs to run through all the sheets. Change the sheet number using a for loop?
Set Dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dest")

'Clear the entire dest sheet before running the logic
Dest.Cells.ClearContents

'h24 is cell where the total rows are filled
Worksheets("Selection").Range("h24").Value = 0
lastRow = 1 ' this always makes the destination to start from first line, overwriting the existing rows

    If (Worksheets("Selection").Cells(1, 5).Value = True) Then

        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Dest").Cells(1, 1)
        lastRow = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

        Worksheets("Selection").Range("h24").Value = lastRow
    End If

    ' Check if second checkbox is selected
    If (Worksheets("Selection").Cells(2, 5).Value = True) Then
        Sheets("Sheet4").Cells.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Dest").Cells(lastRow, 1)

        lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dest").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Worksheets("Selection").Range("h24").Value = lastRow
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds good - let us know if you run into any problems implementing this.  Post the code you're having problems with, and describe what happens when you run it.  If there are errors, make sure to include the error message and which line triggers it.

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: Sorry for not adding the sample code. The wizard does not take you to post sample code while creating the question.